# CHECK length constraint errot in SQLite

Tags: database, sqlite, maxlength

I am trying to add CHECK constraints for my table in database, but I am getting error CHECK Constraint failed everytime I tried adding values in table. It may syntax error for **SQLite**. Thanks in advance.

```
CREATE TABLE `staff` (
`sid`   INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
`sname` TEXT NOT NULL,
`semail`    TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
`sphone`    TEXT NOT NULL CHECK(length ( 'sphone' ) = 10) UNIQUE,
`sdept` TEXT NOT NULL CHECK(length ( 'sdept ' ) = 2),
`spassword` TEXT NOT NULL CHECK(length ( 'spassword' ) <= 8));
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have single quotes around your column names in the constraint clauses; that turns the names into strings.  You should replace the single-quotes with double quotes or omit them altogether.  (You should also replace the back-quotes in your table and column names with either double-quotes or nothing at all to conform to the SQL standard.)

Comment: I also tried it before with no quotes in CHECK length. But It didn't worked either. I am using DB browser, so the syntax other than length is default syntax generated by the browser itself.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no particular knowledge of "DB browser", so I really can't comment on that.  I *suspect* you're doing something wrong, but at this point, you really do have to give more details if you expect an answer.  All I can say is that the snippet you've posted is *not* valid SQL for what you want to achieve.